# How do I execute a simple "apt-get update and upgrade" script using a crontab job?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, vmware, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I created update.sh as following:

```
#!/bin/bash 
       sudo apt-get update 
       sudo apt-get upgrade
       echo "Updated Successfully!
```

and created the following crontab job to run this script every hour:

```
0 * * * *  bash /home/ubuntu/update.sh >> /home/ubuntu/cron_test.txt
```

but only the log file entries of echo command are being created (as I tried running it every minute too) and no confirmation of whether my bash is updating or not. I tried this in both my WSL2 and VMWare Ubuntu terminals. In WSL, it doesn't even log the echo execution entries.
What could be the issue(s)?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, install and configure `unattended-upgrades` which will do all this (and more) for you. Your issue is most likely `sudo` asking for password, which is never provided.

Comment: Being acknowledged that I'm old school, I have never been found of tips and tricks aiming at automatization  of software updates in multi user mode.

Comment: @MC68020 I’m also old-school, but at least `unattended-upgrades` is sufficiently conservative to get a place on my systems, which include real multi-user systems.

Comment: Was able to run my script on AWS Linux EC2 with proper expected logging. As for `unattended-upgrades` this error comes: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate 
Thank y'all for your valuable comments.

Comment: The curse of 200 open browser tabs -- I forgot to come back to this one.  Did you find a solution?  `unattended-upgrades` won't work (easily) on WSL since it relies on Systemd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing a couple of issues, both rooted in the fact that WSL doesn't run Systemd by default (or easily).  I go into detail a bit on this in an [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986) and another on [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1719430/1210833), so I'm not going to deep into that again here.

But without Systemd:

- `unattended-upgrades`, which was suggested in the comments and another answer, won't work.
- You'll need to start `cron` some other way, since it's normally started by Systemd as well on Ubuntu.  Given your comment:

  > it doesn't even log the echo execution entries

  ... it sounds like `cron` isn't running at all, which is to be expected under WSL.

But before I present any possible solutions, let me suggest that you probably shouldn't do this on a WSL instance.  WSL instances aren't designed to be long-running, always-on environments.  They are more like Docker containers running a distribution.  As such, I'd always be worried about an interrupted upgrade happening in the background.  The host OS, a `wsl --shutdown` (or `--terminate`) or any of a number of things could cause the WSL instance to stop while in the middle of a background/unattended upgrade.

On a physical/virtual machine, the `unattended-upgrade-shutdown` can [inhibit shutdown until the unattended upgrade is complete](https://askubuntu.com/q/1098757/1165986).  However, on WSL this isn't possible, which means that Apt data can be corrupted more easily.

This would also be the case with running `apt upgrade` in a `cron` process.

I would recommend just running your `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` manually.  The default MOTD will remind you when it's needed, to some degree.

---

As for running `cron` on WSL, that can be automated a few different ways.  The recommended way is on Windows 11, where there is a `boot.command` config setting available.

If you are on Windows 10, you can add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
wsl.exe -u root service cron status > /dev/null || wsl.exe -u root service cron start > /dev/null
```

That uses the `wsl.exe` command to run as root without requiring a password.

Please see [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1701903/1210833) where I cover both techniques in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues:

1. You are using `sudo` which means it will be prompting for a password and no password is given. So it will just hang there. The simple solution to that is to use root's `cron` (either `sudo crontab -e` or add an entry to `/etc/cron.crontab` with the user root) and so avoid the need for `sudo`.
2. The apt commands themselves also prompt, you need to confirm installation when you run `apt upgrade`. You can get around this too by running `apt upgrade -y`.

Now, both "solutions" above are bad. Please don't use either of them and instead [install unattended-upgrades](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-keep-ubuntu-20-04-servers-updated), a tool designed to do exactly this, and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but actually, surprisingly enough, I was able to run my same script as cron job in AWS Linux EC2 CLI. It logged everything and didn't even ask for the password.

And `unattended-upgrades` apparently doesn't work on WSL as I'm returned with this exact same error when I try to run it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate

Comment: @NavdeepSingh you were probably running it as root. Or you have a system with `sudo` set up to never prompt for a password. Neither is a very good idea. Please clarify if you are asking about WSL or if you are actually using a virtual machine, the two are completely different situations. unattended-upgrades should work fine in the VM, I have no idea about WSL. But the bad workarounds my answer suggests should work in both cases.